# How to setup virtual Active Directory server in Windows 7 OS?

Tags: active-directory, windows-7-x64, adlds

I want to automate the following scenario:

I need install a 3rd party software. During this installation, i need to provide the following info:

1. AD domain name
2. AD domain controller IP
3. AD domain username
4. AD domain password.

If I provide the above info, software will fetch user info from AD.

Instead of creating a separate AD server in another machine,  I want to setup a AD setup in my Windows 7 PC itself.

I have tried AD LDS. But I am unable to get info about how to setup the above FOUR parameters.

Any idea on how to solve this issue?

Is there any open source tool to configure the above setup in Windows 7?